# How can i save Set with mongo-scala-driver?

Tags: mongodb, scala, mongo-scala-driver

I try to save a case class with field of Set type. 
Something like this:

```
case class MyObject(setOfString:Set[String])
```

When I get my MyObject from db, i have this error:

```
The future returned an exception of type: java.lang.ClassCastException, with message: scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon cannot be cast to scala.collection.immutable.Set.
```

Mongo version:

```
"org.mongodb.scala"      %%  "mongo-scala-driver"     % "2.1.0"
```

Any idea how can i force Set type to mongo driver?

Comment: Or you can have a look at [ReactiveMongo](http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.12/documentation/)

Comment: ReactiveMongo does't have bulk write, it's important in my case.

Comment: ReactiveMongo has bulkInsert, BTW `bulkWrite` is a MongoShell operation, not a MongoDB command